# .py script directy into PyCharm

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, pycharm

I've already created a `.py` script in Ubuntu. I'd like to open that script directly into PyCharm from Bash. Could anyone be able to tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :**

If we suppose I've already create a project and a script. My project is called `LearnPython` and my script is called `Test.py`. So the path is `/home/jeremie/PycharmProjects/LearnPython/Test.py`. Then my question becomes : How could I launch `Test.py` from the terminal into PyCharm directly (e.g. `./pycharm.sh /home/jeremie/PycharmProjects/LearnPython/Test.py` (It's not working!!!)) ?

Comment: pycharm will want you to create a project.  When you do that, select the directory with the .py you want to use.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'll explain to you what I mean. If you suppose I've already create such project and script. My project is called `LearnPython` and my script is called `Test.py`. So the path is `/home/jeremie/PycharmProjects/LearnPython/Test.py`. Then my question is : How could I launch `Test.py` from the terminal into PyCharm directly (e.g. `./pycharm.sh /home/jeremie/PycharmProjects/LearnPython/Test.py` (It's not working!!!)) ?

Comment: Please edit the question, to include exactly what you are asking.  There is an edit tag just below your text. Click it, and edit. This will allow you to get a better answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Just tested this on windows, and it works fine for me. But on windows I invoked pycharm directly, not through a script.  Are you sure that ./pycharm.sh invokes the editor successfully and that it passes through any command line arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer Command-line Launcher in Pycharm .

1. Open Pycharm
2. Find tools under menu
3. Select Command-line
   Launcher from there

After then: you can  run a file just by :

```
charm filename
```